# How can I reply to email without losing the previous email chain?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have code to populate email from Excel using VBA. I want to retain previous correspondence and also add my signature to the end of the email.

Code that opens the current Outlook item and populates it. The variable ChsBody is assigned earlier.

```vb
If OutItem.Class = olMail Then
    Set replyEmail = OutItem.ReplyAll
    With replyEmail
        .Signature
        .Body = ChsBody
        .Display
    End With
Else
    MsgBox "ERROR: Make sure email is selected"
End If
```

Would it be possible to retain the email chain and add my response as a string?

Comment: Instead of `.Body = ChsBody` try `.HTMLBody = ChsBody & "<br>" & .HTMLBody`

Comment: Posting it as an answer in case the comment is lost in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible to retain the email chain and add my response as a string?

Change

```
.Body = ChsBody
```

to

```
.HTMLBody = ChsBody & "<br>" & .HTMLBody
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you override the `Body` content with your own:

```
.Body = ChsBody
```

Instead, if you want to preserve the existing content, you need to append the string:

```
.Body = ChsBody & .Body
```

Note, there are three main ways of dealing with message bodies in Outlook:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the `Inspector` class returns an instance of the Word Document which represents the message body.

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.